# Ansible replace to replace a certain regex group

Tags: regex, ansible

I am using the [Ansible replace module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/replace_module.html) to replace a string that is the first group of my regex expression.

```
- name: Replace my_address
      replace:
        dest=/etc/mydata/info.yaml
        regexp="^my_address\W\s(localhost)$"
        replace="{{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}"
```

In my file I have several mentions of `localhost` and I want to replace `localhost` only on the following line: `my_address: localhost`.

So far the code abore replaces the whole line with the IP address. Is there a way to replace only the first group of the regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a lookbehind:

```
regexp="(?<=^my_address\W\s)localhost$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sQ1qP8/2)

Only the consumed part (`localhost`)  will get replaced then, and `(?<=^my_address\W\s)` will just check if there is `my_address` with a non-word character + whitespace before it.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the expression to work for `my_address` and another line like `IP_address: localhost`? I am still not very good with regex.

Comment: Since this is Python, you will need something like [`(?<=^my_address\W\s|^IP_address\W\s)localhost$`](https://regex101.com/r/sQ1qP8/3). Fortunately, the two strings are of the same length.

Comment: Thank you, but now I am curious if there is a way to do this with strings with different length.

Comment: You will have to use an alternation group with the lookbehinds as separate branches: [`'(?:(?<=^my_address\W\s)|(?<=^IP_my_address\W\s))localhost$'`](https://regex101.com/r/sQ1qP8/4) (do not try the alternation inside one lookbehind: it will work at regex101.com, it is a bug on that site). Here is an [IDEONE test](https://ideone.com/DQ3S0C).

Answer (score 2):

To refer specific capturing group, you can use `\g<1>` or `\g<groupName>` in replacement. please refer https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html